# Perl script, find first half of string

Tags: regex, string, perl

Within a Perl script I need to process the following string:

```
426852  total
```

The string will always contain an integer followed by some white space and the word total. I need to strip away the string part of the variable to just leave an integer that I can compare later in the script.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure how to even approach this. My Perl scripting is dreadful. I thought I could maybe use chomp() but not sure how?

Comment: Every tool you need to answer this question yourself is found in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Regular-expressions (perlintro).  It's about a 45 minute read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't need the rest, just finding leading digits is enough:

```
$str =~ /^(\d+)/;
```

`^` - beginning of string, `\d` - digit, `+` - one or more. Result will be in `$1`, captured by `()`

Answer (score 2):

If the number is at the beginning, you can just leave the string as it is. Perl can handle a number that contains something non-numerical after a number (a warning will be issued, though).

Comment: `warnings` will complain though.

Comment: Will it just strip out the string and keep the integer then? This will be the easiest option I guess. I need to keep the number in the variable and then compare that to another variable extracted from a DB.

Answer (score 2):

no need for regex, [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) can do this for you:

```
my $string = '426852  total';
my $number = (split " ", $string)[0];
say $number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regular expression like this:

```
$string =~ /^(\d+)\s+\w+/;
$num = $1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done some work with regex but am by no means competent, could you explain that regex please?

Comment: The `\d+` captures the initial numeric chunk, `\s+` gobbles all the whitespace that follows, while the `\w+` gobbles the entire word that follows the white-space. You need to use the numeric chunk later, so you use parentheses to save it into Perl's memory (the $1,$2 variables), and then assign $1 to another variable $num which you can use later. The reason being that $1 is transient, it's value may change with further successful match, so you should not rely on it.

Comment: Too complicated. You don't need the `\s+\w+` at the end of the regex. And there's a potential bug. If the regex doesn't match, then what will `$1` contain (maybe not undef). Always check the match has succeeded before copying `$1`.

Comment: Well, he himself said that the string under test will **always** contain a number, followed by some whitespace, followed by a word, that's why I didn't bother checking. If he is unsure, of course it will require checking.

Comment: No data is _always_ the way the user describes :-)

Comment: Well, then of course, it will need checking before using `$1`.

Comment: OK so now two different approaches have been suggested - one regex, the other using split. Which is better? (and in terms of checking - you mean checking it's an integer?)

Comment: `Split` is always faster than regex matching, so go for `split`. And regarding the checking, we meant doing a conditional check, like `if ($string ~= /pattern/) {}`, so that in case the match succeeds, only then assign the value of `$1` to `$num`. If you don't do that, and assign `$1` to `$num` straight-away, it will assign the value of `$1` from some previous successful match (`$1` is reset only after successful match) to `$num`, that will give you nasty bugs!

Answer (score 0):

```
my @numbers = map { (split " ", $_)[0] } <DATA>;

print join "\n", @numbers;

__DATA__
126852  total
426852  total
```

Comment: Please excuse me, but what does this do?

Comment: The `__DATA__` is a means of including to-be-used data in the source code for experimenting purpose. When you use this, you can just use `<DATA>` just like a normal filehandle `<file>`, and it will give you each line after the `__DATA__` marker in turn.